# Child thread name is not getting printed inside run()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have following problem. As you can see in the code(inside main()) i am setting name of child threads as "Child1" and "Child2". So when these 2 child threads are running the run() method i am trying to print their names. But as you can see from the output "Child2" thread's name is not getting printed.

Please tell me why this is happening. is there something wrong with the code?

```
package threads_concurrency;

class MyRunnable2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<21;i++)
            System.out.println("Child Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            System.out.println("child thread got interrupted");
        }

    }
}

public class NameIdPriorityValuesOfThread 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Thread main=Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("id of main thread = "+main.getId());
    System.out.println("name of main thread = "+main.getName());
    System.out.println("priority of main thread = "+main.getPriority());

    System.out.println("==================================");

    //Code to create thread1
    MyRunnable2 mr1=new MyRunnable2();
    Thread t1=new Thread(mr1);
    System.out.println("default id of t1 is :"+t1.getId());
    System.out.println("default name of t1 is :"+t1.getName());
    System.out.println("default priority of t1 is :"+t1.getPriority());
    t1.setName("Child1"); t1.setPriority(9);

    System.out.println("==================================");

    //Code to create thread2
    MyRunnable mr2=new MyRunnable();
    Thread t2=new Thread(mr2);
    System.out.println("default id of t2 = "+t2.getId());
    System.out.println("default name of t2 = "+t2.getName());
    System.out.println("default priority of t2 = "+t2.getPriority());
    t2.setName("Child2"); t2.setPriority(9);
    System.out.println("==================================");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    for(int i=1;i<21;i++)
        System.out.println("main thread");

    }

}

*************OUTPUT*****************
id of main thread = 1
name of main thread = main
priority of main thread = 5
==================================
default id of t1 is :8
default name of t1 is :Thread-0
default priority of t1 is :5
==================================
default id of t2 = 9
default name of t2 = Thread-1
default priority of t2 = 5
==================================
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
main thread
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
Child Thread Child1
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
main thread
```

Comment: Hint: study java naming conventions ... no _ in java names!

Comment: in your example you're using 2 different classes. ``MyRunnable`` and ``MyRunnable2``.

Comment: @Janoz good spot - that's why one should think about names and not just append a number, as those differences are hard to spot.

Comment: show code for `MyRunnable` or you used `MyRunnable` by mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Thread 2 you're using `MyRunnable` class instead of `MyRunnable2`

```
MyRunnable mr2=new MyRunnable();
```

Change it to `MyRunnable2` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
MyRunnable mr2=new MyRunnable();
```

You should have

```
MyRunnable2 mr2=new MyRunnable2();
```

to get what you expected :)